# Как данные курсора превратить в массив

Tags: java, android, cursor

Первый код

```
Cursor c = db.query("friends", new String[]{"_id","firstname","lastname"}, "_id" + "<=?", new String[]{"100"}, null, null, null, null);
```

Второй код

```
ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"));  
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);  
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Подскажите теперь как связать эти два кода, чтобы вместо массива `data` во втором коде поставились данные из курсора в первом коде.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать адаптер, который работает с `Cursor` напрямую (`SimpleCursorAdapter`), а не перегонять впустую данные между сущностями, напрасно тратя время и ресурсы устройства

Answer (score 2):

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
    String firstname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstname"));
    String lastname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastname"));
    data.add(firstname + " " + lastname);              
}
```

Comment: Т.е. надо по кусочкам собирать? Никаких путей вроде готовых методов нету. Ну, типо сразу вместо адаптера указать выборку из БД. Чтобы сразу ListView заполнился данными из БД.

Comment: Как сказал @pavlofff , можно и нужно использовать CursorAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

Есть готовый способ *из коробки*, называется `SimpleCursorAdapter`, в конструкторе надо маппить какие поля курсора каким колонкам соответствуют.

[Фтыкать здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)

```
new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.container_list_item_view, null,
                new String[] { MYCOLUMN1, MYCOLUMN2 },
                new int[] { R.id.list_item1, R.id.list_item2 });
```